# How to print for loop in a Label using Java GUI

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

I have got a method that prints a list of students using a forloop. 
I want to print the results of it in a label (using GUI ).
can someone provide a way to print it in a label
**here is the method**

````
public  String printStudents(String name,String ID, String GPA) {

        System.out.println("Student List ");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.myStudents.size();i++){

            name = this.myStudents.get(i).getName();

             ID=this.myStudents.get(i).getIDNumber();
            GPA=this.myStudents.get(i).getGPA();
            System.out.println((i+1)+"."+
                    "Name: "+name +"\n"+
                    "ID  = "+ ID+"\n"+
                    "GPA= "+ GPA +"\n"
                    +"     ~~~~~    ");
        }
        return name+"       "+ID+"      "+GPA;
    } ```
````

Comment: This totally depends on what library you're using (probably Swing) and within that, which classes and stuff you're using and what context it's in. Please try making the code for a general GUI first and then ask this question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JavaFX to show information about students. It is a fast example. You can use another JavaFX component(Label, TreeView) if you wish. I prefer to use TableView to display information on my projects.

For example:

```
package com.javafxbook;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ShowGUI extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        List<Student> students = initStudents();
        Scene scene = new Scene(initTable(students), 600, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Students");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TableView initTable(List<Student> students) {
        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        initTableColumns(tableView);
        tableView.getItems().addAll(students);

        return tableView;
    }

    private void initTableColumns(TableView tableView) {
        TableColumn<String, Student> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        TableColumn<String, Student> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));

        TableColumn<String, Student> gpaColumn = new TableColumn<>("GPA");
        gpaColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("GPA"));

        tableView.getColumns().add(nameColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(idColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(gpaColumn);
    }

    private List<Student> initStudents() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Student("First", "1", "GPA_1"),
                new Student("Second", "2", "GPA_2"),
                new Student("Third", "3", "GPA_3"));
    }

    public class Student {
        private String name;
        private String ID;
        private String GPA;

        public Student(String name, String ID, String GPA) {
            this.name = name;
            this.ID = ID;
            this.GPA = GPA;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getID() {
            return ID;
        }

        public void setID(String ID) {
            this.ID = ID;
        }

        public String getGPA() {
            return GPA;
        }

        public void setGPA(String GPA) {
            this.GPA = GPA;
        }
    }

}
```

And the result will be:
[image]

Comment: is it possible to let the user enter the variable instead of giving the a static value

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: in the code you wrote , you wrote this " 
private List<Student> initStudents() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Student("First", "1", "GPA_1"),
                new Student("Second", "2", "GPA_2"),
                new Student("Third", "3", "GPA_3"));
    }"

Comment: but I want to be able to scan the value from the user

Comment: I had just created a list of users. You can pass  in the ```initTable(List<Student> students)``` method any List you wish (from the database, HTTP request and etc)